# Counts grouped by two columns output into columns & rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, pivot, conditional-aggregation

Let's say I've got some data with two columns: name and ice cream purchases.

```
Joe  | Chocolate
Mary | Vanilla
Beth | Rocky Road
Fred | Vanilla
Mary | Rocky Road
Joe  | Vanilla
Joe  | Chocolate
etc...
```

What I want to do is get the count, grouped by both columns. I know how to do this so that it will output into three columns: name, flavor, and count. However, what I want to do is output it with the names as the rows and the flavors as the columns, like this:

```
     + Vanilla | Chocolate | Rocky Road
Joe  |    1    |     2     |      0
Mary |    1    |     0     |      1
Beth |    0    |     0     |      1
Fred |    1    |     0     |      0
```

Is there a way to do this with just a SQL query? (The database is in SQLite, if that makes any difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(ice = 'Vanilla') Vanilla,
       SUM(ice = 'Chocolate') Chocolate,
       SUM(ice = 'Rocky Road') "Rocky Road"
FROM tablename
GROUP BY name;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9M1bqHndrjPhNPkUC32ajd/0).

Comment: The problem with this is that the real data has unique values in the "flavors" column that number in the hundreds, or even thousands, and items can be added to or removed from the list at any time. Thus, any solution that requires hard-coding every column in the query is unworkable.

Comment: @T.Reed then you should work this out in your application code because SQLite does not support any dynamic pivot functionality.